# ReadAllLines not working and it won't tell me why

Tags: java

I've finally gotten around to learning Java and I'm trying to write an interpreter for an esolang. I looked up a few tutorials and wrote this code.

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NDBall {
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        Path path = Paths.get(input);
        List<String> code = new ArrayList<String>();
        code = Files.readAllLines(path);
    }
}
```

However, the readAllLines function keeps giving me an error, and I don't know why. It won't tell me what the error is, and everything else seems fine. I'm doing it exactly as the tutorials I looked up told me.

Is there some mistake I made?

Comment: *keeps giving me an error, and I don't know why. It won't tell me what the error is,* - this just does not make sense.  Is there some output, if so please post it as part of your question.

Comment: Wrap the call to Files.readAllLines() in a try-catch block and print the error message to the console. This way, you can see the exact error message that Files.readAllLines() is throwing and get a better idea of what the issue might be.

Comment: @coting So... it works now. It only works if I put it in a try-catch. The mystery error is gone.

I guess I have a lot to learn about Java. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work for you. have hard coded the path so escape characters are taken care of:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Solution {

    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\imp.txt");
        List<String> code = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            code = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            code.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).